# How to get full path from "../" on command line in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

If I have a shell script where I get the parent folder using "../" can I expand that out somehow into it's absolute path?

Comment: as far as i remember "pwd" gives you the Parent Working Directory

Comment: @weberik: "print working directory"

Comment: oh ok, remembered wrong, thx for the hint :)

Comment: idea: ask stackoverflow instead of google :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want `readlink -f`.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ readlink -f ..
/
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Linux.  But in case anyone is wondering, `readlink -f` is not supported on OS X.  Then you can use `cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P`

Answer (score 4):

Use `realpath`

```
$ realpath ..
/home
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can often get the full path of a directory using `stat`, you can also use `pwd -P` ... however, it isn't much help unless you actually `cd` to the directory you are interested in.

To get around this limitation without actually changing the current working directory, I've found it fine to just run that `cd` in a *sub-shell*, as in:

```
THIS=`dirname $0`     # Which is often "."
PARENT=$(
  cd $THIS            # At this point, we are sure we're in script's directory
  dirname `pwd -P`
)
echo "PARENT=$PARENT"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using in cmd line:

```
dirname $(pwd)
```

When using in shell script:

```
PROJ_DIR=$(dirname $(pwd))
```